# FullCalendar Recurring Events

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I use recurring events in FullCalendar to represent multi-day events easily. Here is the data for one event:

```
{
"title" : "asdf",
"endTime" : "19:19:00.000",
"endRecur" : "2020-08-06",
"startTime" : "17:19:00.000",
"startRecur" : "2020-08-05"
}
```

My issue, is that even though this is a recurring event, the `endTime` and `endRecur` seem to be ignored. I say this because on my calendar, this event only shows on the 5th. There is nothing displayed for the 6th which is when this event *should* end.

[Documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events)

Edit: Okay it seems this isnt working correctly because I should just define the times within the `Recur` fields. That said, if I have a time set in the `Recur` fields, it is ignored.

So this:

```
{
"title" : "asdf",
"endRecur" : "2020-08-06T19:29:00.000Z",
"startRecur" : "2020-08-05T17:29:00.000Z"
}
```

Renders correctly but no time is displayed. Checking my JS now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation you linked to states, `endRecur` is *exclusive*; meaning the date specified will **not** get one of your recurring events (if it would otherwise fall there). From the page:

> **Note: This value is exclusive.** Just like every other end-date in the
> API. For all-day recurring events, make the `endRecur` the day **after** you
> want your last recurrence.

Taking the advice of the above-quoted paragraph, your solution to the sample you provided might look something like the following:

```
{
"title" : "asdf",
"endTime" : "19:19:00.000",
"endRecur" : "2020-08-07",
"startTime" : "17:19:00.000",
"startRecur" : "2020-08-05"
}
```